# Crop an image, only visible part of it, which is behind another image

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-image, android-bitmap

I want to get the part of an image which is visible to us. There is another image over the first image. So from that image, some part of first image is visible. And I want that part only.
I’ll show you sample of it and final output which I am expecting from it.
[image: Image to crop]

[image: Mask]

[image]

[image]

I know how to crop in oval shape.  But here, the template used in above example can be different in actual, so as per the template /mask I need to crop that image.
 How can I do this. Any idea?

Comment: Try to use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuffXfermode.html)

Answer (score 0):

A simple but maybe not very efficient solution:

- assume the mask is above the real image
- both images are in the same container and if the mask is above the image this means that the pixels of the image would correspond to pixels of the mask
- draw only those pixels of the image whose corresponding pixel in the mask is not black

Comment: I think this will work. But do have any code snippet which i can refer? Thank you!

Comment: I don't have any code to give you but you can take a look at the android guidelines and the documentation for bitmaps, drawables, etc.